# openxyl changes keep reverting back(update: found it out)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

here's an example of the code, it's supposed to change the value of a rows "Is manager" column after you input a name that it finds

```
def demote_name(self,name=''):
    #-------------------Checks if excel is open and whether it should close it or not------------------------       
            if "EXCEL.EXE" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter()):
                t.sleep(2)
                os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM Excel.exe")
                t.sleep(1)
    #-------------------Checks if excel is open and whether it should close it or not------------------------       
    
    #------checks if there is an employee here by inputted name, whether it should use the selected employee or not, whether there are 2 employees by 1 name,as well as if the employee is a manager------------------------
            try:
                if name == '':
                    name = self.name
            except AttributeError:
                print('you need to specify which employee you wanna promote, either by doing emloyee.select_by_name(name) then employee.promote_name() or employee.promote_name(name)')
                sys.exit()
            file = pd.ExcelFile('Zenex worker data.xlsx')
            data = pd.read_excel(file, self.sheetvalue)
            if name not in data['Name of employee'].values:
                print('There is no employee by the name {0} (this is case sensitive so make sure your typing it in right)'.format(name))
                sys.exit()
            data = data[data['Name of employee'] == str(name)]
            if len(data) != 1:
                print('there are 2 employee by the name {0}, try searching by employee ID'.format(name))
                sys.exit()
            d = data['Is Manager'].values
            d = ' '.join(map(str,d))
            r = type(self)
            r = str(r)
            r = r = r.split('.')
            r = r[-1].replace("'", "")
            r = r.replace('>','')
            if d == 'Yes' or 'Executive': 
                if r == 'Zenex_Xmanager':
                    pass
                else:
                    print('This employee is a manager and or executive so you dont have athority to select or edit them')
                    sys.exit()
                
    #------checks if there is an employee here by inputted name, whether it should use the selected employee or not, whether there are 2 employees by 1 name,as well as if the employee is a manager------------------------
    
            for row in self.sheet.iter_rows():
                for cell in row:
                    if cell.value == name:
                        self.sheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=10).value = 'No'
            self.wbk.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Zenex worker data.xlsx'))  
            self.wbk.close
            
            try:
                if name == self.name:
                    del self.is_manager
                    del self.ID
                    del self.name
                    del self.race
                    del self.salary
                    del self.position
                    del self.increase
                    del self.gender
                    del self.worked
                    del self.date_created
            except AttributeError:
                pass
```

When I demote somebody while the excel file does change the value to "No" after I run another method that edits the excel it changes back to its previous value, is there any way I can fix it?

--------------------------------------------------Update---------------------------------------------------

I was able to fix it because in order to be able to call the workbook I assigned it as an attribute, as you can see over here since it has self in front: `self.sheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=10).value = 'No'` and that basically create 2 versions of the notebook whenever I was using 2 objects, if your gonna make a class using openxyl then assign the stuff such as `wbk = openpyxl.load_workbook` as class variables instead and call of them like you would a class variable, maybe this is common programming knowledge but just in case

Comment: The code is far too extensive, please provide a simpler example.

Comment: @CharlieClark i just edited it, is this good now?